# Exclude "Status" from serialized output of Kubernetes objects

Tags: go, kubernetes, serialization, yaml, client-go

I would like to serialize a Subscription resource (from `github.com/operator-framework/api/pkg/operators/v1alpha1`) to YAML using code like this:

```
    subscription := operatorsv1alpha1.Subscription{
        TypeMeta: metav1.TypeMeta{
            APIVersion: operatorsv1alpha1.SubscriptionCRDAPIVersion,
            Kind:       operatorsv1alpha1.SubscriptionKind,
        },
        ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{
            Namespace: namespaceName,
            Name:      pkg.Name,
        },
        Spec: &operatorsv1alpha1.SubscriptionSpec{
            Package:                pkg.Name,
            Channel:                channel.Name,
            InstallPlanApproval:    operatorsv1alpha1.Approval(subscribeFlags.Approval),
            CatalogSource:          pkg.Status.CatalogSource,
            CatalogSourceNamespace: pkg.Status.CatalogSourceNamespace,
        },
    }

    operatorsv1alpha1.AddToScheme(scheme.Scheme)
    corev1.AddToScheme(scheme.Scheme)

    serializer := json.NewSerializerWithOptions(
        json.DefaultMetaFactory, scheme.Scheme, scheme.Scheme,
        json.SerializerOptions{
            Pretty: true,
            Yaml:   true,
            Strict: true,
        })

    if err := serializer.Encode(&subscription, os.Stdout); err != nil {
        return err
    }
```

This works, except that `operator-framework/api` defines a `Subcription` resource like this:

```
type Subscription struct {
    metav1.TypeMeta   `json:",inline"`
    metav1.ObjectMeta `json:"metadata"`

    Spec *SubscriptionSpec `json:"spec"`
    // +optional
    Status SubscriptionStatus `json:"status"`
}
```

Which means that the serialized output always includes a `status` element with a null `status.lastUpdated` field:

```
apiVersion: operators.coreos.com/v1alpha1
kind: Subscription
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: argocd-operator
spec:
  channel: alpha
  installPlanApproval: Automatic
  name: argocd-operator
  source: operatorhubio-catalog
  sourceNamespace: olm
status:
  lastUpdated: null
```

Submitting the serialized manifest fails with:

> error: error validating "STDIN": error validating data: ValidationError(Subscription.status): missing required field "lastUpdated" in com.coreos.operators.v1alpha1.Subscription.status; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

Is there a canonical method for serializing these resources without including the `status` field?

Comment: Did you finally managed to find a solution? From what I can see, `lastUpdated` always appear because it does not have an `omitempty` option (`json:"lastUpdated,omitempty"` [here](https://github.com/operator-framework/api/blob/v0.20.0/pkg/operators/v1alpha1/subscription_types.go#L235)) and is not a `*metav1.Time` but a `metav1.Time`. Same for `SubscriptionStatus` (no `omitempty`: https://github.com/operator-framework/api/blob/v0.20.0/pkg/operators/v1alpha1/subscription_types.go#L324). I don't know why it's made like this in this library though...

Comment: Usually (for example when using kubebuilder), all fields have this `omitempty` option (e.g. https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubebuilder/blob/v3.13.0/docs/book/src/cronjob-tutorial/testdata/project/api/v1/cronjob_types.go#L176) to avoid serializing empty fields. So I feel like this is a flaw in the library implementation, but I might be wrong.